# Flutter - PictureRecorder crash in release mode (Android)

Tags: android, image, flutter, bitmap, crash

My code to generate bitmap descriptors to display marker bitmaps on google map:

```
Future<BitmapDescriptor> getMarkerBitmap({String categoryId, bool isSelected = false}) async {
    int size = (25 * globals.devicePixelRatio).toInt();
    double radius = 7 * globals.devicePixelRatio;

    var dictionary = [globals.categories.event, globals.categories.suggestions].expand((x) => x).toList();
    var category = dictionary.firstWhere((element) => element.id == categoryId, orElse: () => null);
    String iconName = category != null ? category.iconName : null;
    String text = fontawesome.fontAwesome[iconName ?? "exclamation-circle"] ?? fontawesome.fontAwesome["exclamation-circle"];

    final PictureRecorder pictureRecorder = PictureRecorder();
    final Canvas canvas = Canvas(pictureRecorder);
    final Paint paint1 = Paint()..color = isSelected ? Colors.green : Colors.blue;

    final Paint paintBorder = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 3.0;
    
    RRect rrect = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
        Rect.fromLTWH(
          0,
          0,
          size.toDouble(),
          size.toDouble(),
        ),
        Radius.circular(radius));

    canvas.drawRRect(rrect, paint1);
    canvas.drawRRect(rrect, paintBorder);

    if (text != null) {
      TextPainter painter = TextPainter(textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
      painter.text = TextSpan(
        text: text,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: size / 1.5, color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'Fontawesome', fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
      );
      painter.layout();
      painter.paint(
        canvas,
        Offset(size / 2 - painter.width / 2, size / 2 - painter.height / 2),
      );
    }

    final img = await pictureRecorder.endRecording().toImage(size, size); //<----CRASH!
    final data = await img.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);

    return BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List());
  }
```

Above method is called in `initState` approx 50 times, all is fine. Then, when my app displays other page, then again map page, above method is called again 50 times and app crash occurs:

```
15:51:03.193 13180 27036 F libc    : FORTIFY: pthread_mutex_lock called on a destroyed mutex (0x6e3a839460)
05-22 15:51:03.193 13180 27036 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 27036 (GLThread 3675), pid 13180 (app.myapp)
05-22 15:51:03.229  1043  4533 E ANDR-PERF-LM: GamePerfEngine: runAsyncPeriodic() 590: AppState st 0
05-22 15:51:03.285 13180 23418 F libc    : FORTIFY: pthread_mutex_lock called on a destroyed mutex (0x714857a3d0)
05-22 15:51:03.285 13180 23419 F libc    : FORTIFY: pthread_mutex_lock called on a destroyed mutex (0x714857a3d0)
05-22 15:51:03.285 13180 26449 F libc    : FORTIFY: pthread_mutex_lock called on a destroyed mutex (0x6e4dfd2298)
05-22 15:51:03.288 27043 27043 I crash_dump64: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
05-22 15:51:03.288   780   780 I tombstoned: received crash request for pid 27036
05-22 15:51:03.290 27043 27043 I crash_dump64: performing dump of process 13180 (target tid = 27036)
05-22 15:51:03.295 27043 27043 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-22 15:51:03.295 27043 27043 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'OnePlus/OnePlus9Pro_EEA/OnePlus9Pro:11/RKQ1.201105.002/2105011307:user/release-keys'
05-22 15:51:03.295 27043 27043 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
05-22 15:51:03.295 27043 27043 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
05-22 15:51:03.296 27043 27043 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2021-05-22 15:51:03+0200
05-22 15:51:03.296 27043 27043 F DEBUG   : pid: 13180, tid: 27036, name: GLThread 3675  >>> com.company.my.app <<<
05-22 15:51:03.296 27043 27043 F DEBUG   : uid: 10401
05-22 15:51:03.296 27043 27043 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
05-22 15:51:03.296 27043 27043 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'FORTIFY: pthread_mutex_lock called on a destroyed mutex (0x6e3a839460)'
05-22 15:51:03.296 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :     x0  0000000000000000  x1  000000000000699c  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000006d39025110
05-22 15:51:03.296 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :     x4  0000000000008080  x5  0000000000008080  x6  0000000000008080  x7  0000000000000038
05-22 15:51:03.296 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :     x8  00000000000000f0  x9  06cf147a3d3fe09c  x10 0000000000000000  x11 ffffffc0fffffbdf
05-22 15:51:03.296 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :     x12 0000000000000001  x13 00000118a1ce8dda  x14 000b3e20c38e6b8d  x15 0000000034155555
05-22 15:51:03.296 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :     x16 000000714ba16c80  x17 000000714b9f8b70  x18 0000006d2eeca000  x19 000000000000337c
05-22 15:51:03.296 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :     x20 000000000000699c  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 0000006d39029420  x23 0000006d39025380
05-22 15:51:03.296 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :     x24 0000000010000900  x25 0000000000000b33  x26 00000000000005a0  x27 0000006d3902b000
05-22 15:51:03.296 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :     x28 0000006d3902b000  x29 0000006d39025190
05-22 15:51:03.296 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :     lr  000000714b9ac3e0  sp  0000006d390250f0  pc  000000714b9ac40c  pst 0000000000001000
05-22 15:51:03.307 27043 27043 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
05-22 15:51:03.307 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 000000000004e40c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164) (BuildId: 07fbaeed7b7a19203975f06be6f1d5ef)
05-22 15:51:03.307 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 00000000000b1724  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__fortify_fatal(char const*, ...)+124) (BuildId: 07fbaeed7b7a19203975f06be6f1d5ef)
05-22 15:51:03.307 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 00000000000b0d20  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (HandleUsingDestroyedMutex(pthread_mutex_t*, char const*)+52) (BuildId: 07fbaeed7b7a19203975f06be6f1d5ef)
05-22 15:51:03.307 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :       #03 pc 00000000000b0b78  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (pthread_mutex_lock+160) (BuildId: 07fbaeed7b7a19203975f06be6f1d5ef)
05-22 15:51:03.307 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :       #04 pc 00000000000963a8  /apex/com.android.vndk.v30/lib64/libc++.so (std::__1::mutex::lock()+8) (BuildId: cd7d36d61219edf4da7d788565b373c7)
05-22 15:51:03.307 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :       #05 pc 000000000000b6c8  /vendor/lib64/libgrallocutils.so (gralloc::AdrenoMemInfo::GetInstance() (.cfi)+36) (BuildId: 503a70f75a883710cdc57fa54881f60d)
05-22 15:51:03.307 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :       #06 pc 0000000000007930  /vendor/lib64/libgrallocutils.so (gralloc::GetBufferSizeAndDimensions(gralloc::BufferInfo const&, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, GraphicsMetadata*) (.cfi)+56) (BuildId: 503a70f75a883710cdc57fa54881f60d)
05-22 15:51:03.307 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :       #07 pc 000000000000788c  /vendor/lib64/libgrallocutils.so (gralloc::GetBufferSizeAndDimensions(gralloc::BufferInfo const&, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, unsigned int*) (.cfi)+116) (BuildId: 503a70f75a883710cdc57fa54881f60d)
05-22 15:51:03.307 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :       #08 pc 000000000000d604  /vendor/lib64/libgralloccore.so (gralloc::BufferManager::ValidateBufferSize(private_handle_t const*, gralloc::BufferInfo)+84) (BuildId: b30091a6ca681d2e5d68628b17e20780)
05-22 15:51:03.307 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :       #09 pc 000000000000c580  /vendor/lib64/hw/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@4.0-impl-qti-display.so (vendor::qti::hardware::display::mapper::V4_0::implementation::QtiMapper::validateBufferSize(void*, android::hardware::graphics::mapper::V4_0::IMapper::BufferDescriptorInfo const&, unsigned int)+184) (BuildId: 657e4c0680cc5424b3491c4e32860b80)
05-22 15:51:03.307 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :       #10 pc 0000000000010118  /system/lib64/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@4.0.so (android::hardware::graphics::mapper::V4_0::BsMapper::validateBufferSize(void*, android::hardware::graphics::mapper::V4_0::IMapper::BufferDescriptorInfo const&, unsigned int)+168) (BuildId: e1d324d2dade6fab12a4ad74b55f6a27)
05-22 15:51:03.307 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :       #11 pc 000000000002ea08  /system/lib64/libui.so (android::Gralloc4Mapper::validateBufferSize(native_handle const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, unsigned int, unsigned long, unsigned int) const+192) (BuildId: c5bf22a215c97e6514b3eaa7d8b7961b)
05-22 15:51:03.307 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :       #12 pc 00000000000390f4  /system/lib64/libui.so (android::GraphicBufferMapper::importBuffer(native_handle const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, unsigned long, unsigned int, native_handle const**)+220) (BuildId: c5bf22a215c97e6514b3eaa7d8b7961b)
05-22 15:51:03.307 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :       #13 pc 00000000000370ec  /system/lib64/libui.so (android::GraphicBuffer::unflatten(void const*&, unsigned long&, int const*&, unsigned long&)+688) (BuildId: c5bf22a215c97e6514b3eaa7d8b7961b)
05-22 15:51:03.307 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :       #14 pc 00000000000e78c0  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::Parcel::FlattenableHelper<android::GraphicBuffer>::unflatten(void const*, unsigned long, int const*, unsigned long)+60) (BuildId: 3b5caf554fabd6283ba9f03b94513fb6)
05-22 15:51:03.307 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :       #15 pc 0000000000064dd0  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::Parcel::read(android::Parcel::FlattenableHelperInterface&) const+564) (BuildId: 360a7fcf3a708c98a7ff7625fe4fa895)
05-22 15:51:03.307 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :       #16 pc 0000000000098cf4  /system/lib64/libgui.so (android::BpGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer(int, android::sp<android::GraphicBuffer>*)+300) (BuildId: 60ab8ac7885161359a42a1a573724bb3)
05-22 15:51:03.307 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :       #17 pc 00000000000b7768  /system/lib64/libgui.so (android::Surface::dequeueBuffer(ANativeWindowBuffer**, int*)+716) (BuildId: 60ab8ac7885161359a42a1a573724bb3)
05-22 15:51:03.307 27043 27043 F DEBUG   :       #18 pc 0000006e38b149b0  <unknown>
05-22 15:51:03.316  1799  2447 W InputDispatcher: channel 'a138f90 Sys2030:com.company.my.app/my.app.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
05-22 15:51:03.316  1799  2447 E InputDispatcher: channel 'a138f90 Sys2030:com.company.my.app/my.app.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
05-22 15:51:03.316  1799  2447 W InputDispatcher: channel '981ae5d com.company.my.app/my.app.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
05-22 15:51:03.316  1799  2447 E InputDispatcher: channel '981ae5d com.company.my.app/my.app.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
05-22 15:51:03.181  1799  1913 D OpScreenModeService: VRR WM [POST] isADFRPkg false packageName: com.company.my.app dismissADFR: false mViewRate: 1 mLowFreqVideo: false
05-22 15:51:03.317  1799  3385 I VirtualDisplayAdapter: Virtual display device released because application token died: com.company.my.app
05-22 15:51:03.318   805   805 I Zygote  : Process 13180 exited cleanly (1)
05-22 15:51:03.318  1799  1912 I DisplayManagerService: Display device removed: DisplayDeviceInfo{"flutter-vd": uniqueId="virtual:com.company.my.app,10401,flutter-vd,0", 1440 x 2867, modeId 948, defaultModeId 948, supportedModes [{id=948, width=1440, height=2867, fps=60.0}], colorMode 0, supportedColorModes [0], HdrCapabilities null, allmSupported false, gameContentTypeSupported false, density 460, 460.0 x 460.0 dpi, appVsyncOff 0, presDeadline 16666666, touch NONE, rotation 0, type VIRTUAL, deviceProductInfo null, state ON, owner com.company.my.app (uid 10401), FLAG_PRIVATE, FLAG_NEVER_BLANK, FLAG_OWN_CONTENT_ONLY} ownerUid:10401
05-22 15:51:03.318  1799  5575 I ActivityManager: Process com.company.my.app (pid 13180) has died: fg  TOP 
05-22 15:51:03.318  1799  3147 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{a138f90 u0 Sys2030:com.company.my.app/my.app.MainActivity}
05-22 15:51:03.318  1799  3147 W InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'a138f90 Sys2030:com.company.my.app/my.app.MainActivity (server)'
```

Interesting it crashes only in release mode. When app is running in debug mode, no crashes at all. Do you have any ideas? That was actually hard to track, as I am unable to debug.